# Position of y-axis on the right side Python panel (holoviz)

Tags: python, bokeh, panel, holoviz

how can I change the position of the y-axis labels to the right side? The standard is of course on the left side, but I want to have it on the right side.
I can’t find anything in the holoviz panel documentation to it.

I tried to derive it from the position settings of the legend. So, I thought  `p.y_axis_label_text_align = 'right’`  could be right. However, it does not work.
Can anybody help me out or has a Python panel example where the y-axis is located on the right side of the chart tile? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the package you are using.

**Holoviews**

If your figure is created with holoviews, please cheack out the [holoviews documentation for axis-positions](https://holoviews.org/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html#axis-positions).

In gerneal

```
.opts(xaxis='top', yaxis='right')
```

does the trick.

**bokeh**

If you are using the the `figure` of `bokeh.plotting`, then

```
p = figure(..., y_axis_location="right", ...)
```

moves the one y-axis to the right.

In case you want to add a new axis, the [twin-axis example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-3.0/examples/plotting/file/twin_axis.py) shows how to add a `LinearAxis`.